# Opening a .ppkx ArcGIS Pro file in QGIS or ArcMap

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro

I'm helping with a research project at the moment, and I'm having a hard time getting ArcGIS Pro. (I run Linux Mint for the most part, but I have access to Windows computers at school).

Data that was shared with me has a .ppkx file extension, is there anyway I can view this data or open this project in QGIS or in ArcMap?

Comment: Asking how to do something in one of two GIS software products makes this effectively two questions which goes against the [Tour].

Comment: Try renaming the .ppkx extension to .7z and uncompress the file using 7-Zip. https://twitter.com/kgjenkins/status/1542256028275859459

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro package files are not backward compatible with ArcGIS v10x.  ArcGIS Pro package files are proprietary data and not usable in non Esri (ArcGIS Pro) applications like QGIS.

If your school had access to ArcGIS Pro, open the package and save out the data for use in QGIS.

If you are a student, try getting a [student version of ArcGIS Pro](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-for-student-use/overview).

Alternatively, pay for a [non-commercial license](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-for-personal-use/buy).

One other thing to try is to uncompress the .ppkx file using 7-Zip (you may need to rename the .ppkx extension to .7z) and you should be able to read the data using QGIS. Source: [Twitter/X](https://twitter.com/kgjenkins/status/1542256028275859459)